# Can MahApps.Metro be used in MvvmCross?

Tags: wpf, mvvmcross, mahapps.metro

I was trying to use Mahapps Metro inside a WPF project using MvvmCross mvvm framework.

Both seem to use custom window control. Is there a way to use both in a project?

Metro window:

```
<mah:MetroWindow  x:Class="TipCalc.WPF.MainWindow"
              xmlns:mah="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
              xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
              xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TipCalc.WPF"
              xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf"
              mc:Ignorable="d"
              Title="MainWindow"
              Height="450"
              Width="800">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</mah:MetroWindow>
```

MvvmCross Window:

```
<views:MvxWindow  x:Class="TipCalc.WPF.MainWindow"
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
              xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
              xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
              xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TipCalc.WPF"
              xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf"
              mc:Ignorable="d"
              Title="MainWindow"
              Height="450"
              Width="800">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</views:MvxWindow>
```

The application runs either way. But with the Metro window in place, the rest of the application doesn't get set up(ie.-children views). With the MvvmCross window in place, the application works as usual but is not designed or colored.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since multi inheritance is not supported in C#, this is not possible out of the box.

But a look at the source code of [MvxWindow](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross/Platforms/Wpf/Views/MvxWindow.cs) shows it's no big class. So a potential solution could be creation of your own window. This window, let's call it `MvxMetroWindow`, could collect both functionalities by inheriting from `MetroWindow` and aditionally all the source code of `MvxWindow` added (copied from the original source code) by yourself.

This would look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

using MahApps.Metro.Controls;

using MvvmCross;
using MvvmCross.Binding.BindingContext;
using MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf.Views;
using MvvmCross.ViewModels;
using MvxApplication = MvvmCross.Platforms.Wpf.Views.MvxApplication;

namespace TipCalc.WPF
{
    public class MvxMetroWindow : MetroWindow, IMvxWindow, IMvxWpfView, IDisposable
    {
        private IMvxViewModel _viewModel;
        private IMvxBindingContext _bindingContext;
        private bool _unloaded = false;
        //... Further implemenetation of original MvxWindow
    }
}
```

The custom window finally can be used like this:

```
<local:MvxMetroWindow x:Class="TipCalc.WPF.MainWindow"
                      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TipCalc.WPF"
                      ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! Just might be a pain to have to change update that anytime MvvmCross updates.

Comment: I tried, this out but doesn't seem to work anymore probably due to changes to MvvmCross. Is there a newer version or workaround for this?

Comment: Since there are no changes in the MvXWindow since then, I think it should still work. What are the issues you are facing?

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg I can confirm that this workaround still works. Just used it today and everything works fine.